# One and half Inch Floor Threshold

Tags: flooring

Thank you for this space. If I had searched earlier I probably would have saved myself over $1000 and avoided lots of tears.

I bought a home with a step down from my living room to my kitchen and a step down from my dining room to my kitchen about one and a half inches ( I think that's about  38.1 mm step down). I am in need of two-floor transitions. One is just a tab over 91 inches and the other 31 1/2 inches. There are two entryways in my kitchen. I need help. I've had 4 different people come and look at the floor. Two have charged me and the work is still not done. Please advise. I am about to lose my mind. Help, please ;-)

Comment: Hi Taylor, pictures will help

Comment: Do the transitions need to go over both floors or just need it for the lip?

Comment: If you paid money and got no service/work it becomes a lawyer question.  Depending on difficultly transitions can be done by yourself if you have tools or get them made at wood shops.  It will depend on what you want, so if you post a picture or two it will help.  Right now making a angle/slope on a 2x4 should work.